# How to assign char pointer value to an integer/char variable or array

Tags: c

Been a while since I did any C programming. I wanted to know how to assign a value of `char` pointer to an array or a variable. 
Example:

```
char *line;
int v[100];
v[0]=atoi(line);
```

I am basically reading a file line by line using `getline()` and it returns a `char *` and I wanted to save the data from each line in an array.

Comment: use `strcpy` or `strncpy` to get the input copied from buffer of `getline` to that array - you might need to typecast the `char *` to `const char *`.

Comment: @Fairy Add `getline()` function call, I guess something wrong with this entity because the last two lines sintatically correct.

Answer (score 0):

John Kugelman

First, I mostly program in the Windows and OpemVMS environments.  I do not have direct access to the GNC’s getline function.  My answer is based on both my C experience and reading [GNC implementation of getline()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html).  My answer assumes you are using the following version of getline();

```
ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream);  // Non delimited version
```

As stated by Observer, the best method is to use some type of function to copy the data.  (Note it is possible to use a FOR loop without a copy function).   There is something you have to watch out for.  The data being returned can be larger than your array receiving it.  To safe guard again this, you should verify the copy length before copying.

```
char v[100] = {0}, *line = null;

len = getline ( &line, . . . .  );


// Method for coping null terminated data
copyLen =  (len < 100)? len : 99 ;
strncpy ( v, line, copyLen );
v[copyLen]=0; 

Or

// Method for coping data with embedded nulls
copyLen =  (len <= 100)? len : 100 ;
memcpy ( v, line, copyLen );
```

**Things to note:**

- The copy length is computed to be the lowest value that will fit in
  the array.
- If data is a null terminated string, array elements 0 – 98 are use for data,
  the 99 element is use for the place holder for the null terminator.  Note the
  null terminator can actual be in any position (0-99) depending on the data
  length read in.
- If data contains null embedded data, all 100 elements are used for
  storing the data.